# Catch double tuples in Sqlite3 (by primary key)

Tags: python, sqlite

i buil a db with some tables. In every table is min. one primary key.
If i insert a new tuple which already exist - TRACEBACK:

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO kfehlzeit VALUES (?,?)", row)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: columns TDA, PAY are not unique
```

This is right, but how can I catch this? Because after this - there are much rows to insert..

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "catch"? What should happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use try/except. It is very generic, but this will allow to continue if it fails to insert the row into table.